# How to configure parse sdk client to receive push notification in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I've changed some code and compiled the latest parse SDK for .net plugin for unity. Now I want to configure unity client app to receive a push notification (especially android). I don't know how to configure it, I've just found some code to receive or show the notification not how to configure it like all permission or where to put cloud message key. If someone could help me? thanks

Comment: Please, take a look in this guide: http://docs.parseplatform.org/unity/guide/#push-notifications

Comment: Thanks. guide refer to how to use it, not how to configure it. I think problem is on parse sdk for unity because it's work fine when i use sdk for android. i use in same time firebase sdk and parse sdk, when i send push directly from firebase it's work but not in parse server.

Comment: Have you completed all this steps [here](http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#push-notifications-quick-start)?

Answer (score 1):

yes, of course. I've found something strange, i have two messages receiver firebase and parse, firebase receiver  work when app is in foreground    `

```
    //Events subscription
    private void Awake()
    {
        instance  = this;
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
        ParsePush.ParsePushNotificationReceived += OnMessageReceiveByParse;
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += 
        OnMessageReceiveByFirebase;
    }

    // method call when firebase message received
    void OnMessageReceiveByFirebase(object 
sender,Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.Log("Message from firebase : " + args.Message);
    }

    // method call when parse message received
    void OnMessageReceiveByParse(object sender, ParsePushNotificationEventArgs args)
    {

        Debug.Log("Message from Parse Server : " + args.Payload);
    }

    // parse guide receiver implementation
    void cool(object sender, ParsePushNotificationEventArgs args)
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        AndroidJavaClass parseUnityHelper = new AndroidJavaClass("com.parse.ParsePushUnityHelper");
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

        // Call default behavior.
        parseUnityHelper.CallStatic("handleParsePushNotificationReceived", currentActivity, args.StringPayload);
#endif
    }
```

`

I use android studio to debug when app is launched, an error is always shown, i use classes parse sdk not compiled dll: this classe doesn't exist in my sdk:

```
    (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)
2019-07-12 09:12:33.968 14620-14663/? E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.parse.ParsePushUnityHelper
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.parse.ParsePushUnityHelper
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativePause(Native Method)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.l(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$22.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:32)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.parse.ParsePushUnityHelper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wmg.mascothunt-bUi8a5Uz_-d12IhMoYJuOQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.wmg.mascothunt-bUi8a5Uz_-d12IhMoYJuOQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.wmg.mascothunt-bUi8a5Uz_-d12IhMoYJuOQ==/base.a
```

Answer (score 0):

Making **outdated and expired Parse** to work with unity/android build should be your last option in pursuit of a notification API.(btw it may have worked with Unity prior to 2016)

if you use the original way of copying Parse.Unity.dll you'll end up with a duplicate class Task since Unity already added it in its newest versions.

```
Type Task<> exists in both Unity.Tasks and mscorelib
```

the way to solve that is by using the extracted dll provided [here](https://github.com/scode-cmd/Parse-for-Unity-2018) but that is not intended for push notifications, it is usefull for database only. because you'll get:

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.parse.ParsePushUnityHelper
```

you need to know that parse in Unity is handled by the [parse .NET SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/tree/f577ee38a0d55a199a473065b18acad084e4b083) and parse in android is handled by [parse android SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android), the problem starts when you try to use the unity project to create android apk, in that case the .NET SDK lacks the Android dependencies thats why you're getting class not found, parse uses `Reflection` and `AndroidJavaClass` to convert some of it's android SDK to utilize them in .NET SDK, those java classes need to be manually extracted from already released SDKs and be manipulated for your purpose.

you need ParsePush.jar to solve `ParsePushUnityHelper not found exception`, you can get the classes to build it in [here](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/tree/f577ee38a0d55a199a473065b18acad084e4b083/ParsePush/Native/src/main/java/com/parse), when you bring it to your Unity project, you get duplicate classes, and a bunch of other dependency errors, the way to fix that is to create the ParsePush.jar yourself, for that you need the Unity dependency which is a classes.jar. you can find it in parse github, they use it. I have also added my whole project that I could successfully achieved this in [here](https://github.com/Alireza-Jamali) both android and unity versions are there.

you also need to delete the Unity dependency when you put it inside your Asset/Plugins/Android/ folder since Unity is already provided in there.

One things that just insanely confused the hell out of me was that DeviceToken is not generated at your will, YOU NEED TO CLEAR CACH CLEAR DATA UNINSTALL your app then run it again to have DeviceToken generated for you by firebase and without it you will not receive notifications.